# Parameter passing to Linux C inline functions

Tags: c, inline-functions

When calling a non-`inline` function with two integer or pointer parameters from a C program, they are passed in registers `rdi` and `rsi`. Can the compilation be done in such a way that integer/pointer parameters to **`inline` functions** are passed in registers as well (and **not** on the stack)?

Answer (score 6):

When a function is inlined, it is treated as if its code was written into the function that called it. When this happens, it is not passed parameters at all.

When a function isn't inlined, it's absolutely no different from a normal function. `inline` is just a hint to the compiler to try and inline a function; it doesn't affect linkage at all.

Comment: Correction, inline functions *may* be inlined, usually at the compiler's discretion.

Answer (score 3):

Counter question: Why do you care? I think you shouldn't. That's your compilers job. If you don't trust your compiler to do the right thing there, you probably shouldn't use one at all.

And I'm pretty sure your assumption that parameters are ever guaranteed to land in registers is false as well.

Answer (score 0):

in C the first two int's are not passed into %rdi and %rsi... that is an ABI / Calling Convention issue... Not a language issue.

if the function does get inlined and the rest of the surrounding code permits it, the int's will likely be in a general purpose registers...

but this is absolutely not your concern... and if you care, you can just have the compiler generate the asm to read and learn from...